# VSPackgae VSIX throws exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, vsix, vspackage

I developed a VSpackage and tried to install the VSIX file on my VS.

When I tried to open the extension - Tools-> Other Window - My Extension, I got a message box saying `An exception has been thrown by the target of invocation`

Note: this is the first time i'm trying to run the extension not on the Experimental instance

After a little bug fixing i got this exception on the same way:

`System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension`

Comment: I just added a detailed exception details

Answer (score 0):

Do you experience the same behaviour if you run the experimental instance without attaching a debuggger? If yes, check your exception handling settings for debug mode. Probably throwing is disabled which might be the reason why everything seems to work, because you won´t get notified about exceptions...